# Effects of subtracting numbers in a set of random variables on their mean and standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, statistics

This is a question about linear combinations of independent random variables.
X and Y are independent random variables.
$X$ has mean 2 and standard deviation 4.
$Y$ has mean 3 and standard deviation 2.
How would you calculate the mean and standard deviation of  $X - Y$?

I know that if a set of random variables are all added by k then the mean becomes mean+k 
but since we are adding the numbers by different numbers, how would this work?

Comment: If the random variables X and Y are normal, then the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables.  Variance is the square of the standard deviation.  For the more general case, see: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sum+of+independent+random+variables&l=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mean is linear in its argument, i.e.
$$
\mathsf E(X-Y) = \mathsf EX-\mathsf EY.
$$

About the standard deviation you know that the variance of sum of independent random variables is equal to the sum of their variances, i.e.
$$
V(X+Y) = V(X)+V(Y)
$$
and the standard deviation is a  positive square root of the variance: $\sigma_X = +\sqrt{V(X)}$. What you still need to do is to recall that $V(Y) = V(-Y)$, so
$$
\sigma_{X-Y} = \sqrt{V(X-Y)} = \sqrt{V(X+(-Y))} = \sqrt{V(X)+V(-Y)}
$$
$$
=\sqrt{V(X)+V(Y)} = \sqrt{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2} = \sqrt{20} = 2\sqrt{5}.
$$

For more information see these articles: [expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) and [variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).